# how to generate ed25519 keypair pem file in java

Tags: java, ssh, rsa, bouncycastle, ed25519

I generated ed25519 keypair with my code, but when i copy the public key file and private key file to the linux machine.It looks like there is something wrong with my key pair file.
[linux machine can't login with keypair file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZI6qJ.png)

this is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    createED25519();
}

private static void createED25519() throws IOException {
    KeyPairGeneratorSpi.Ed25519 ed25519 = new KeyPairGeneratorSpi.Ed25519();
    ed25519.initialize(256, new SecureRandom());
    KeyPair keyPair = ed25519.generateKeyPair();
    PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
    PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();

    writeEd25519PrivateKey(privateKey);
    writeEd25519PublicKey(publicKey);
}

private static void writeEd25519PrivateKey(PrivateKey privateKey) throws IOException {
    try (PemWriter w = new PemWriter(new FileWriter("D:\\keypair\\Ed25519\\java.pem"))) {
        Ed25519PrivateKeyParameters ed25519PrivateKeyParameters = (Ed25519PrivateKeyParameters) PrivateKeyFactory
                .createKey(privateKey.getEncoded());
        byte[] content = OpenSSHPrivateKeyUtil.encodePrivateKey(ed25519PrivateKeyParameters);
        PemObject o = new PemObject("OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY", content);
        w.writeObject(o);
    }
}

private static void writeEd25519PublicKey(PublicKey publicKey) throws IOException {
    try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("D:\\keypair\\Ed25519\\java.pub")) {
        Ed25519PublicKeyParameters publicKeyParameters = (Ed25519PublicKeyParameters) PublicKeyFactory
                .createKey(publicKey.getEncoded());
        String publicKeyPub = "ssh-ed25516 " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(OpenSSHPublicKeyUtil.encodePublicKey(publicKeyParameters));
        fileWriter.write(publicKeyPub);
    }

}
```

pom.xml:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.67</version>
    </dependency>
```

The content of the generated public key is:

```
ssh-ed25516 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIJC+iPZZ56a7wogB/UxlmSbrN2hjaOnu26b2pVX6zkZr
```

The content of the generated private key is:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAAAMwAAAAtz
c2gtZWQyNTUxOQAAACCQvoj2Weemu8KIAf1MZZkm6zdoY2jp7tum9qVV+s5GawAA
AIhAEzACQBMwAgAAAAtzc2gtZWQyNTUxOQAAACCQvoj2Weemu8KIAf1MZZkm6zdo
Y2jp7tum9qVV+s5GawAAAED5xx3tLFBLSXC/SE1dSKL3vuUs9mj2+3/086sbXePu
TJC+iPZZ56a7wogB/UxlmSbrN2hjaOnu26b2pVX6zkZrAAAAAAECAwQF
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Hope someone can tell what's wrong with the code, or is there any other way to generate the ED25519 key pair file for SSH login, thanks!

Comment: Any update about this question?

Answer (score 0):

I think the fact that there has been no response, is there is likely nothing wrong with your code, getting a password prompt is more indicative of sshd_config.d/overrides.conf issues. Ensure `PubkeyAuthentication yes` is present.  Then when trying to ssh, using (multiple) `-v` flags to find the issues, e.g `ssh -vvv user@host`.  This is not a java issue, unless you can't verify the public key against the private key, in code.

Edit: When looking at the verbose output, check to see if there is anything wrong with `id_ed25516` rather than `id_ed22519` of your public key file. That part is hardcoded via string here `String publicKeyPub = "ssh-ed25516 "`